# Undefined virtual field mongoose when using arrow function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, mongoose, arrow-functions

I am new to mongoDB.

this is my schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        //remove whitespaces
        trim:true,
        //minimum length
        min:3,
        max:20
    },
    lastName:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        min:3,
        max:20
    }
})
```

Everything is fine till here.But now I wanted to create a virtual property and hence did this:

```
//virtual property
userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(()=>{
    console.log("first name " + this.firstName);
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
});
```

But `this` returns `undefined` because `this` is empty.
But when I use the normal `function` keyword to create the function it solves the issue.
Doesnt the `arrow` function bind `this` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the ES6 arrow function which can't bind `this`. After all, `this` is already bound.

More on this topic here: [Understanding "this" in javascript with arrow functions](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc)

Try the same with normal function keywords like the following

```
userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function () {
  console.log("first name " + this.firstName);
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript ES6. Arrow Function do not have context. The `this` keyword points to the window object. use `function name(){}` if you want use `this` keyword